# Pillow: libopenjp2.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, raspbian, python-imaging-library

I have a fresh, minimal Raspbian Stretch install. I have installed the PIXEL-dekstop by running `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg`
 and am now trying to use Pillow in Python. Pillow was installed by running `sudo apt-get install pip3` and then `sudo pip3 install Pillow`. Whenever I try `from PIL import Image` I get the error `ImportError: libopenjp2.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

I have attempted to reinstall Pillow under different versions but it does not help. I have also enabled apt-get sources in `/etc/apt/sources.txt` and ran `sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging`, which also did not help. Any help is appreciated.

Python version: 3.5.3, current Pillow version: 4.3.0

Comment: execute: `sudo apt-get install libopenjp2-7-dev`

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you, this solved it. Do you have any tips for how I could (in general) find the right packages when I'm missing dependencies? How did you find out about `libopenjp2-7-dev`?

Comment: I just google: ubuntu libopenjp2.so.7 since many of the raspbian packages are the same as ubuntu, and then enter the first link: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libopenjp2-7, Then remember that the -dev packages are for developers and that is what they are needed.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 81):

What worked for me was running :

```
sudo apt-get install libopenjp2-7
```

Good Luck!

Comment: YESSS! That worked for me on Raspbian.  I then had a similar error regarding libtiff.so.5 and solved it with ```sudo apt-get install libtiff5```

Comment: Thanks! I had to do this additional step too!

Comment: Also had to do the following for installing the [face_recognition](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) library. In summary:

`sudo apt-get install libopenjp2-7 libtiff5 libatlas-base-dev`