# How to install .so file via conda?

Tags: python, dependencies, conda, .so

When I do:

```
from PIL import Image
```

It gave:

```
ImportError: libopenjp2.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48012582/pillow-libopenjp2-so-7-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo) that suggests to do

```
sudo apt-get install libopenjp2-7-dev
```

However, in my case, it is not doable since I'm operating a remote computation system and I am not able to do sudo command. Since I found there are many .so files in lib directory under Miniconda, I wonder whether can I install this libopenjp2.so.7 via conda install? How?

Comment: A *.so file is a shared object. Conda should install all dependencies. Can you open a prompt, do "conda list" and post the output here?

Comment: Here's a list of [all external libraries](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/installation.html#external-libraries) used by Pillow. These should be installed before executing Pillow commands. And if they are not present on standard path (which I doubt coz you dont have admin privileges), require additional commands in Pillow to work. Have you tried searching the system if `libopenjp2` is present or not.

Comment: @Dschoni  Yes you are right, conda install can solve dependencies. However, due to the reason that I have to use virtualenv not conda env, pip install is the only choice.(Some pre-built wheels on HPC are only available in virtualenv)

Comment: @Vivek Kumar I did search by using 
    find . -name "libopenjp2*", but I can't find this object. There is also no libopenjp2 in the link you provided.

Comment: The above link has `'openjpeg'`. openjp2 is an library in that.